# OrderBy exception "At least one object must implement IComparable"

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list.

This line throws the exception: ;

```
List<DistanceInfo> ListedDuration = 
              Distances.OrderBy(o => o.Rows[0].Elements.OrderBy(e => e.Distance))
                       .ToList();
```

But, this works:

```
List<DistanceInfo> ListedDuration = 
              Distances.OrderBy(o => o.Rows[0].Elements[0].Distance)
                       .ToList();
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: By using your second example? It's not clear what you actually want to do. Perhaps some explanation?

Comment: BTW are you sure that there always will be at least one row in every distance object? And yes, it's not clear how you want to sort your distances.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky yeah im sure, every time one row. i want ascending sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at:

```
List<DistanceInfo> ListedDuration = Distances.OrderBy(
    o => o.Rows[0].Elements.OrderBy(e => e.Distance)
).ToList();
```

The thing we are ordering by is:

```
o => o.Rows[0].Elements.OrderBy(e => e.Distance)
```

which is to say; for each item `o`, order it by **the sequence** ordered by distance `o.Rows[0].Elements.OrderBy(e => e.Distance)`. That doesn't make much sense. How do you compare two *sequences*, such as `{1,3,4}` to `{1,8}` ?

You might, however, take the *first* distance, or the *min* / *max* distance:

```
List<DistanceInfo> ListedDuration = Distances.OrderBy(
    o => o.Rows[0].Elements[0].Distance
).ToList();

List<DistanceInfo> ListedDuration = Distances.OrderBy(
    o => o.Rows[0].Elements.Min(e => e.Distance)
).ToList();

List<DistanceInfo> ListedDuration = Distances.OrderBy(
    o => o.Rows[0].Elements.Max(e => e.Distance)
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see below, For this issue i have tried with same query used two order by like below, works for me

```
 List<DistanceInfo> ListedDuration = Distances.OrderBy(o => 
 o.Rows[0].Elements[0].Distance).OrderBy(o => o.Rows[0].Elements[0].Distance
 ).ToList();
```