# groupping/sorting/splitting 2D list/array

Tags: c#, linq, multidimensional-array

I have following 2D array

```
var array1 = new string[][]
            {
              new string[] {A,B,C},
              new string[] {A,X,Y},
              new string[] {D,L,K},
              new string[] {A,X,W}

            };
```

At the end I would like to sort or group this list and output I want to display on my MVC view on a table as below

A / X /  Y,W

/ B/  C

D/ l / K

I dont want to show repeated elements in the column. So it means like groupping.

- How can I group the results in controller with linq.
- Sorting might also help if I can sort by first element and then 2nd etc.
- Another idea also works that if I can split into 3 1D arrays? So at the end i would have array1 ={A,A,D,A}, array2={B,X,L,X}, array3= {C,Y,K,W}

Thanks.

Comment: This should be pretty easy with LINQ. What have you tried?

Comment: sorting answer is indeed here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197230/sort-2-dimensional-list-based-on-first-indexvalue  It would work for the first element but sorting together for 2 elements. I cant figure out

Comment: Groupping is easy with 1D but 2D, I am sorry I cant figure out. Same for splitting. Of course I would split it easily using for loop but I wonder if any simple way exist with linq.

Comment: Have a look at the `GroupBy` method (or `group by` LINQ keyword). And don't think about your data as a 2D array - it's a simple 1D array of rows. The fact that the rows themselves are also arrays is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem should be split into two subproblems. First, you need to sort the `array1`; second, you need out `array1` using the fact the `array1` is sorted.

You can't use grouping instead of sorting, cause a grouping is not guarantee that subarrays with the same first element will follow each other.

```
var array1 = new List<IList<string>>
{
    new List<string> {"A", "X", "Y"}, 
    new List<string> {"A", "X", "W"}, 
    new List<string> {"A", "B", "C"}, 
    new List<string> {"D", "L", "K"}, 
};

var array2 = from a in array1
    orderby a[0], a[1], a[2]  
    select a;

var array3 = array2.ToList();
```

Now you can use `array2` in Razor:

```
@if (array2.MoveNext())
{
   @array2.Current[0], @array2.Current[1], @array2.Current[3]<br />

   var lastElement = array2.Current;
   while (array2.MoveNext())
   {
     if (array2.Current[0] != lastElement[0])
     {
       @array2.Current[0],
     }
     else if (array2.Current[1] != lastElement[0])
     {
       @array2.Current[1],
     }

     @array2.Current[2]
     lastElement = array2.Current;
   }
}
```

Comment: your answer sounds solution for me but I get a complain that "At least one object must implement IComparable." when I want to cast to array2 to my return object. my return object is Ilist. not sure if it something to do with that but this guy has exactly same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335943/orderby-exception-at-least-one-object-must-implement-icomparable
according to the answer, it looks to me that order part is causing problem. am I correct?

Comment: what i mean is , of course i can simply return array2 but for my purpose i have to use predefined object and this object is implemented as var myreturnObject = new List<IList<mytype>>();     and when i try to cast myreturnObject =array2,ToList() , I get the this error.

Comment: @batmaci var array1 = new List<IList<string>>
    {
        new List<string> {"A", "X", "Y"}, 
        new List<string> {"A", "X", "W"}, 
        new List<string> {"A", "B", "C"}, 
        new List<string> {"D", "L", "K"}, 
    };

    var array2 = from a in array1
                        orderby a[0], a[1], a[2]  
                        select a;

    return array2.ToList();

Comment: array1 is already implemented like that    var array1= new List<IList<mytype>>();    array1=getArray1values(); But still when use the linq code var array2 = from a in array1
    orderby a[0], a[1], a[2]  
    select a;  This returns an Iorderedenumerable and I am not able to convert to Ilist or List. thanks for your help

Comment: @batmaci **var array3 = array2.ToList();** I have this code compiles and runs without any errors.

Comment: I cant make it working unfortunately. I tried exactly same code. maybe it is because of return type of array2 is different for each of us. my return type is System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IList<mytype>,mytype>  

this is how it looks like when I debuged and I cant use ToList method on it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with all my compiled code. Try to check.

Comment: Sorry, I am being silly. Of course your example was for string and it works fine. my problem was with the using complex type and i had to a property of the type in the orderby as below . 
 var array2 = from a in array1
    orderby a[0].Id, a[1].Id, a[2],Id
    select a;

this way it works fine. thanks again.:)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
var array1 = new string[][]
{
    new string[] {"A","B","C"},
    new string[] {"A","X","Y"},
    new string[] {"D","L","K"},
    new string[] {"A","X","W"},
};

var s = array1.Select(a => string.Concat(a)).ToList();          
s.Sort();
// Now you have them sorted as a list of strings, do what you want...
```

this will not limit you to 3 entries (didn't like the hardcoded [0],[1] etc...)